# How to connect to network share drive programmatically?

Tags: ios, ipad

I would like to write a program on iPad to connect network share drive (similar to FileBrowser application). However, I cannot find many resources and sample code on the Web. Does anyone know how to do it? Any website for reference? Thanks so much!

Comment: The shared drive over the network is probably using some sort of protocol, like FTP, AFP, SFTP, etc. It is required to know which protocol is in use.

Comment: I want to connect to share drive using smb protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting to an SMB shared drive would be the same as connecting to any SMB server. Now I've googled a bit and found that SMB was developed by Windows, and not given free, but that it has been successfully reversed engineered and that it has been ported to Linux, Unix, whatever by the name Samba.

I dug a bit deeper and easily found this link: [Windows Filesharing library for iOS](http://38leinad.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/windows-filesharing-library-for-ios/). It provides a link to [an iOS framework](https://github.com/38leinaD/tango) which enables you to connect to a Samba/SMB drive.

Since I never tried to connect to a SMB/Samba server, I don't know if the framework will work, I've never tested it. But by copying some source files to your own project you normally should get it working.

**Note:** Check the license of any third-party framework you use.

Comment: I believe this framework doesn't work with the Win7 authentication... right?

Comment: yes this framework does not work after win xp version